# Asp.net on IIS Log Files?

Tags: asp.net, iis, logfile

I've a web application running on IIS.
It's a Visual Studio Project with asp pages.

Now my questions:

1) If i need a log where i can see who access the site (at least datetime and ip or something like this) how i can do this???

2) It's possible?

Probably you have to know this: i don't have registration/login in the application.

I can use some IIS tools?? Or i need to write code??
I've try to find something on the net but i prefer a direct question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can browse to the IIS logs on the server it is hosted on. To do this you first need to find the application ID of the site with the problem in IIS. To do this click on your site name in IIS and click on advanced settings in the actions pane. Here you will see the ID of the site. Remember this.

Next you need to browse to C:\inetpub\logs\logfiles if C is the root of your file system and you have installed a default IIS instance. If you haven't then it should be within inetpub.

You will see a series of folders, one for each site setup in IIS, with a naming convention like this W3SVCx. X is what you application ID is.

Within this folder you will see active log files, one for each day the site was browsed too, with the date of the log within the file name (u_exYEARMONTHDATE)